# Product of two matrices of convex combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-polytopes

How to show that product of two matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ of convex combinations  as $\mathbf{C=A*B}$ is also a matrix of convex combinations.

Convex combinations: entries of each column of matrix are non-negative and they sum to 1.

Comment: "Convex combination" is what's usually called "stochastic", right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I guess the word "stochastic" is used in reference to a square probability/transition matrix. In my example none of the matrices are square. I would probably use the term "convex combination" or a combination that is "conic & affine". May be I am not missing anything?

Comment: OK, I guess I assumed the matrices were square. Anyway, Sebastian seems to have settled things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just turn being a convex combination into vector arithmetic: $(1, \ldots, 1) \cdot C = (1, \ldots, 1) \cdot A \cdot B = (1, \ldots, 1) \cdot B = (1, \ldots, 1)$. The non-negativity is clear I suppose.

Comment: Hi, can you provide more details. What about sum to one constraint.?

Comment: That's exactly what this answer shows. Also it seems more common to call these matrices *left stochastic* or *column stochastic* rather than "being convex combinations".

Comment: @Dirk Thanks all for the help. Cheers!